# Find all $n$, such that $\Im\{(i+2)^{n}\}=1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Find all $n$, such that $\Im\{(i+2)^{n}\}=1$.

For $n=1$, we have $\Im\{(i+2)\}=1$. For $n=2$, we have $\Im\{(i+2)^{2}\}=\Im\{4i+3\}=4$,and for $n=3$, we have $\Im\{(i+2)^{3}\}=\Im\{11i+2\}=11$, .. and I hope the other powers are distinct to one, but how I find some $n$ s.t. satisfy the question?

Comment: Have you tried putting it in e-power form?

Comment: I found $$n = \dfrac{\sin^{-1}(1/\sqrt{5}) + 2\pi k}{\tan^{-1}(1/2)} \vee \dfrac{-\sin^{-1}(1/\sqrt{5}) + (1-2 k)\pi}{\tan^{-1}(1/2)}$$ But now there's determining when $n$ is an integer.